# Swift CustomReflectable doesn't work in separated static library

Tags: swift, reflection

Swift CustomReflectable doesn't work if it's been implemented in separated file in separated static library.

```
//  BBB.swift
public struct BBB {
    public var xcv = 344
    public init() {}
}

//  BBB.mirror.swift
extension BBB: CustomReflectable {}
public extension BBB {
    var customMirror: Mirror {
        return Mirror(
            self,
            children: [
                "xxx": 342,
                "www": 999])
    }
}
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, with Xcode 10 and 11 Beta 2, Swift `CustomReflectable` doesn't work if 
- It's in separated static library.
- It's implemented using `extension`.

You can try to move protocol conformation to type's main file like this, and it'll work for now.

```
// Put protocol conformation here!
public struct BBB: CustomReflectable {
    public var xcv = 344
    public init() {}
}
public extension BBB {
    var customMirror: Mirror {
        return Mirror(
            self,
            children: [
                "xxx": 342,
                "www": 999])
    }
}
```

I don't know why, but this works.